# How can I have an array uniform buffer block in glsl?

Tags: opengl, glsl

The error I get with the following declaration of a buffer is:

> Binding point for uniform block must be equal or greater than 0 and
> less than: GL_MAX_UNIFORM_BUFFER_BINDINGS.

My GL_MAX_UNIFORM_BUFFER_BINDINGS is 90. I want 128 of the following structs:

```
layout(binding = 3, std140) uniform lightsBuffer
{
    mat4 viewMatrix;
    vec3 colour;
    float padding;
}lights[128];
```

It seems I've created 128 of these structs each at different binding points. How do I have the array of 128 structs at binding 2?

Edit: Is it like this:

```
layout(binding = 3, std140) uniform lightsBuffer
{
    struct Light
    {
        mat4 viewMatrix;
        vec3 colour;
        float padding;
    }lights[128];
};
```

Comment: And if you're going to have padding, just use a `vec4`.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Can I define the Light struct inside or do I have to define struct Light { } beforehand, and then do what you said?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a struct; it's a uniform block. You can tell because you didn't use the keyword `struct` ;) So what you're creating is an array of uniform *blocks*.

If you want an array *within* a uniform block, you can create that using standard syntax:

```
layout(...) uniform lightsBuffer
{
    StructName lights[128];
};
```

Where `StructName` is a previously-defined `struct`.

> Can I define the Light struct inside

No. Why would you want to?

Comment: I see, define the struct beforehand. It cannot be inside the block like I did?

Comment: @Rabbid76 What I meant was something like uniform lightsBuffer { struct Light { float a; } lights[128]; }; This seems to have worked in my program.

Comment: @Zebrafish: Then your compiler has a bug. The grammar technically allows it, but there's a [explicit statement in the text forbidding it](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.html#interface-blocks): "*Structure definitions cannot be nested inside a block*"